# repetitive element in array algorithm

Tags: java

Can someone help me find the error in my logic for the following code?

I am supposed to print out the array elements only once (value vise)

```
public class dfdf 
{
    public static void main(String...args)
    {
        System.out.println(args.length);
        String a= "1234512";

        for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j <= (i); j++)
            {                    
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    System.out.print(a.charAt(i)); break;
                }
                else if (a.charAt(j) == a.charAt(i))                        
                {
                    break;
                }             
                else    
                {
                    System.out.print(a.charAt(i));}
                } 
            }           
        }            
    }
}
```

> desired output=12345 real output-123344455552

Comment: ohky added `break` to the last `if` condition a;so..now it is printing 123452....have to take care of the 0 index now

Comment: Why the C++ and C tags?

Comment: because it can relate to general algo also..plus i need help..interview in about 2hours

Comment: If you interviewed with me, I'd fail you because you can't tell the difference between C, C++ and Java.

Comment: Asking for help on SO 2hrs before an interview doesn't seem like the right way to prep...

Comment: :( .... a fey syntax changes and the code would hold true for any language... but right now all i need is for you guys to point out the error

Comment: your logic error is `if(i!=0 && a.charAt(j)!=a.charAt(i)) System.out.print(a.charAt(i));`. It must unlike all previous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String a="1234512";

    for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++){
        boolean already = false;
        for(int j = i - 1; j >= 0; --j){
            if(a.charAt(j)==a.charAt(i)){
                already = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(already == false){
            System.out.print(a.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```